# Delphi Oracle Blob

Tags: delphi, oracle, oledb, blob

Здравствуйте! В Delphi создал приложение, которое вытаскивает разные файлы из blob-полей таблицы БД (Oracle 10g). Использую компонент ADOConnection с Oracle Provider for OLE DB, все корректно работает в Windows XP. А вот уже на ОС выше уровнем (Win 8) в списке провайдеров компоненты АDOConnection нет этого Oracle Provider for OLE DB и соотв-но прога не работает (проект не компилится). Может какой-то компонент надо установить? Например, Oracle ODAC там или ODT?

Comment: Вам нужно установить ODAC (он включает в себя Oracle Provider for OLE DB) скачать можно с [оф. сайта](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html), только нужно подобрать версию, но как мне кажется он обратно совместим.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую)